# docker share data between containers when one spins the other

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have a container with a dedicate [data volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume) named *spinner*, which writes data to this volume. the *snipper* can spin up containers.

when the *snipper* spin up a container and tries to mount the same data volume with the *spinnee* container, the volume as no files.

here is an example to demonstrate this

```sh
$ docker run --rm -it --name spinner -v data:/data -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock alpine /bin/sh
/ # apk update -qq && apk add docker -qq
/ # cat /data/foo
foo 
/ # hostname
27a807a0bd01
/ # docker run --rm -it --name spinnee -v /data:/data alpine /bin/sh
/ # 759d96c4ba39
/ # ls -l /data
total 0
```

the matter can be bypassed by using the same data volume, meaning that *spinner* can spin the *spinnee* by specifying the same data volume. such as

```sh
/ # docker run --rm -it --name spinnee -v data:/data alpine /bin/sh
/ # hostname
38dec687817c
/ # cat /data/foo
foo
```

another way to bypass it, is to use [external volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external) and manage it. correctly

the thing is, the *spinner* spin container by leveraging docker-compose and was also span using docker-compose, so that each of which will have a data volume with auto-generated name.

how can i make the *spinner*, which has no notion it runs within a container, to provide a transparent volume share between itself and the container it spins up (i.e. *spinee*)?

Comment: Your second `docker run` command mounts the host path `/data`, not the named volume `data`.  You cannot mount a directory from one container to another.  In general, if you can design around it, it's better practice to not dynamically launch containers and to not share files with containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze: i am aware of all that you said and even notes how i can bypass it. since both containers are being span up using docker-compose, it makes it very problematic to know the docker volume that both will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [--volumes-from](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volumes-from-container---volumes-from). It doesn't fulfill all  your requirements (the `spinner` still needs to be aware of being running inside a container), but at least you don't need to specify the volume by name.

```sh
$ docker run --rm -it --name spinner -v data:/data -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock alpine /bin/sh
/ # apk update -qq && apk add docker-cli -qq
/ # echo "It works!" >> /data/test.txt
/ # docker run --rm --name spinnee --volumes-from "$(hostname)" alpine /bin/sh -c "cat /data/test.txt"
It works!
```

Comment: this is more elegant than specifying the data volume name. yet, when you take into consideration that each of which is orchestrated by docker-compose, the `volumes-from` does not have such native support. maybe i should consider the use of [external volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external)

Comment: Indeed, in the d-c v3 volumes_from is not supported anymore (it was present in the v2)